# Expression templates require redundant overload

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I am creating a simple array class based on expression templates. In the code below, I need to create an overload of the `operator=` function, in order to make it work, even though it is an exact copy of the function above. The reason is (according to GCC) because the default copy assignment is disabled by the compiler. Is there a way to avoid the overload and tunnel it through the templated function?

The main program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Array.hpp"

int main()
{
    const int itot = 10;
    Array_1d a(itot);
    Array_1d b(itot);

    for (int i=0; i<itot; ++i)
        a(i) = i;

    b = 0.;

    a.print();

    b(7,10) = a(1,4);
    b.print();
}
```

The `Array_1d` header:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Array_1d
{
    public:
        Array_1d(const int itot) :
            itot(itot), data(nullptr)
        {
            data = new double[itot];
        }

        Array_1d(const int itot, double* data) :
            itot(itot), data(data)
        {}

        // Deletion needs to be solved.
        ~Array_1d()
        {}

        void print()
        {
            for (int i=0; i<itot; ++i)
                std::cout << i << " = " << (*this)(i) << std::endl;
        }

        double& operator()(const int i) { return data[i]; }
        double operator()(const int i) const { return data[i]; }

        Array_1d operator()(const int is, const int ie) const { return Array_1d(ie-is, data+is); }

        template<class T>
        inline Array_1d& operator= (const T& __restrict__ expression)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<itot; ++i)
                (*this)(i) = expression(i);

            return *this;
        }

        // Why is this specialization necessary?
        inline Array_1d& operator= (const Array_1d& __restrict__ expression)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<itot; ++i)
                (*this)(i) = expression(i);

            return *this;
        }

        inline Array_1d& operator= (const double value)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<itot; ++i)
                (*this)(i) = value;

            return *this;
        }

    private:
        const int itot;
        double* data;
};
```

Comment: `return this->operator=<Array_1d>(expression)`?

Comment: BTW, you will have access out of bound if `expression.itot < this->itot`...

Comment: @Jarod42. That is the next problem to crack :).

Answer (score 2):

Even though you did not write it explicitly, the implicitly deleted copy-assignment operator still "exists" and is a better match than the templated one, which is why it is chosen when you assign from a `Array_1d`.

You can explicitly call the templated method from the non-templated one:

```
Array_1d& operator= (const Array_1d& __restrict__ expression)
{
    return this->operator=<Array_1d>(expression);
}
```

Comment: But can you explain me why this is necessary, as the functions fits the template perfectly? Can copy constructors never be generated from templates?

Comment: @Chiel Answer updated. A class always has a non-templated copy-assignment operator: user-defined or not.

Comment: Thanks. So this is the only solution?

Comment: @Chiel With your current design, yes.

Comment: I had that before, but the ranging through `A(0,3)` creates only a view to the data with the pointer, while with an `std::vector<double>` it would trigger a copy.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `const` member, so it cannot be overwritten:

```
const int itot;
```

and so default copy is disabled.

It seems `const` should be removed.

but then default copy would just copy the pointer of `double* data`;

You probably just need `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: Where does that cause a problem? I never change `itot` beyond the initializer list in the constructor.

Comment: @Chiel A `const` member cannot be assigned another object naturally so the compiler isn't able to generate a copy assignment operator (well any assignment operator) and rightfully so